# Exibir foto do usuário logado a partir da SESSION

Tags: php, mysqli, session, phpmyadmin

Há dias  estou com problemas nesse código em PHP. Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de cadastro de usuários simples, mas estou usando níveis de acesso, até ai tudo bem! Já consigo exibir o nome do usuário através de `SESSION`. Só que agora, eu **gostaria de exibir a foto do usuário logado, cadastrada no banco**.

**Como fazer isso?**

Aqui está a Validação do meu usuário ao fazer login

```
<?php
session_start();    
//Incluindo a conexão com banco de dados
include_once("conexao.php");    
//O campo usuário e senha preenchido entra no if para validar
if((isset($_POST['email'])) && (isset($_POST['senha']))){
    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']); //Escapar de caracteres especiais, como aspas, prevenindo SQL injection
    $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['senha']);
    $senha = md5($senha);

    //Buscar na tabela usuario o usuário que corresponde com os dados digitado no formulário
    $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$usuario' && senha = '$senha' LIMIT 1";
    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);

    //Encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
    if(isset($resultado)){
        $_SESSION['usuarioId'] = $resultado['id'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] = $resultado['niveis_acesso_id'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioEmail'] = $resultado['email'];

        if($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "1"){
            header("Location: dashboard/administrativo.php");
        }elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "2"){
            header("Location: dashboard/vendedor.php");
        }elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "3"){
            header("Location: dashboard/usermaster.php");
        }else{
            header("Location: cliente.php");
        }
    //Não foi encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
    //redireciona o usuario para a página de login
    }else{  
        //Váriavel global recebendo a mensagem de erro
        $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha Inválido";
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
//O campo usuário e senha não preenchido entra no else e redireciona o usuário para a página de login
}else{
    $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha inválido";
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

?>

```
<img src="dist/img/default-50x50.gif" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá!
Primeiro tem que saber como esta salva a foto no banco, esta na mesma tabela que você está selecionando?

Ex:

```
$_SESSION['usuarioFoto'] = $resultado['foto'];
```

Dai você colocaria o caminho ou apenas o nome da foto

```
<img src="imgs/user/<?=$_SESSION['usuarioFoto'];?>" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
```

Comment: Mas eu preciso referenciar essa SESSION  aonde valida os usuário, como eu estou fazendo para nome? Se sim, como faço para concatenar a SESSION  e a pasta?

Comment: Basta vc fazer a concatenação onde vc esta setando a session: $_SESSION['usuarioFoto'] = 'img/user/' . $resultado['foto'];